# Google SignIn with firebase in flutter Exception PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-signin, unhandled-exception

I am trying googleSignIn with Firebase in flutter .My App is Already connected with Firebase firestore and Does Read/Write (Crud) Operations Perfectly.NOw I want to Integrate GoogleSignIn .But I am Getting an Un-handled exception.. I have Tried a tons of Solution of this Platform Answers and Github ,But Unfortunately non of them could solve my problem.

```
E/flutter ( 2995): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: ,null)
```

[image]

```
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
     await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);

final AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

assert(user.email != null);
assert(user.displayName != null);
assert(user.photoUrl != null);

name = user.displayName;
email = user.email;
imageUrl = user.photoUrl;

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();

assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
```

Comment: On Stack Oveflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Couldn't you read the Picture by clicking on it ?

Comment: It's easier for everyone, and the expected convention on Stack Overflow, to copy the text instead of using a picture.  If you disagree, I suggest reading through this conversation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [SHA1](https://buildcoding.com/create-and-add-sha1-fingerprint-to-firebase-project/) to the Firebase project if you haven't done so.

This is Code 10 exception. With "sign_in_failed" error. You can get a report [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report) with same instructions on setting up SHA1.

Comment: Are you using Google People API by any chance?

Comment: no ,, Do i need to Add Google people Api ? if yes then Why I should use it?

Comment: I was simply asking due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776534/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception)

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed my Problem,Actually the main problem was due to change of Package name in firebase and in my project.. Previously I used to replace the package name in json file, whenever I had to read and write the data    in firebase.Hope this may help someone in future.